# Custom column in Power-Query with mixed data types

Tags: powerbi

I want to create a custom column in Power-Query-Editor, and I have two different column types:

```
Number     RequestedDate
110            03.12.2019
100            30.04.2020
```

The new column should look like:

```
Code
10003.12.2019
10030.04.2020
```

How can I do so, the code: `[Number]&[RequestedDate]`gives an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible to solution is to use the formula `Text.From`, then you convert the numeric type and the date type to text form:

```
=Text.From([Number])&Text.From([RequestedDate])
```

That should work in "create custom column".